# Add different labels in a line chart - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to plot some information that the `X-axis` is the time and the `Y-axis` is the a numerical value. The structure is similar to the next table,

```
Name   Date   Result
N1     9:00   88
N1     9:10   84
N1     9:16   83
N1     9:23   83
N1     9:29   85
N2     9:03   87
N2     9:07   87
N2     9:18   87
N2     9:25   86
N2     9:29   86
```

Thus, what I need with this example, are two independent lines that each one work with it data.

To show this info I'm using `chart.js`. My first idea was to use the `scatter` type graph, but this is not possible because it only works with numerical values. Therefore, I thought about using the `line` type graph, but the problem with this is that by default you can only define a single `label` and how you can see I need each information to be independent since they don't have to match the hours.

Is it possible to add another `label`? I've tried to define two lists but it doesn't work and I don't know how to deal with it.

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("my_chart").getContext("2d");

my_chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [
            ['9:00','9:10','9:16','9:23','9:29'],
            ['9:03','9:07','9:18','9:25','9:29']
        ],
        datasets: [{ 
            data: [88,84,83,83,85],
            label: "N1",
            borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
            fill: false
        }, { 
            data: [87,87,87,86,86],
            label: "N2",
            borderColor: "#c45850",
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Info'
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT: My modifications with the help of @alonas and @HeadhunterKev**

This is what I have now, is not working I suppose the format is wrong but I don't know what. Maybe I need seconds? Probably is a silly question but I'm lost with this...

```
var sData = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset1',
        data: [{
            x: '09:00',
            y: 88
        }, {
            x: '09:10',
            y: 89
        }, {
            x: '09:13',
            y: 86
        }, {
            x: '09:23',
            y: 86
        }, {
            x: '09:26',
            y: 85
        }, {
            x: '09:29',
            y: 83
        }]
    }, {
        label: 'Dataset2',
        data: [{
            x: '09:02',
            y: 88
        }, {
            x: '09:13',
            y: 89
        }, {
            x: '09:14',
            y: 86
        }, {
            x: '09:20',
            y: 86
        }, {
            x: '09:24',
            y: 85
        }, {
            x: '09:29',
            y: 83
        }]
    }]
}

sData.datasets[0].data = formatData(sData.datasets[0].data)
sData.datasets[1].data = formatData(sData.datasets[1].data)

function formatData(oldData) {
    var newData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < oldData.length; i++) {
        var currentData = {}
        currentData.x = moment(oldData[i].x, "hh:mm").format('HH:mm')
        currentData.y = oldData[i].y
        newData.push(currentData)
    }
    return newData
  }

var data = sData

var options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
        }]
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            title: function(tooltipItem, data){
                return moment(tooltipItem[0].label).format('hh:mm')
            }
        }
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('bateria_graf');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Can somebody help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: i guess you can use keys ```axisY: { title: 'axisY' }, axisX: { title: 'axisX' }``` in your ```options``` object next to ```title```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand it, can you write an example? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can provide data as a list of x,y:

```
datasets: [{ 
        data: [{y:88,x:`${timestamp of 9:00}` },...],
        ...
    }, { 
        data: [{y:87, x:`${timestamp of 9:03}`},...],
        ...
    }]
```

like here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point

And then in options define how to display the x value (timestamp) as hour:minutes

```
{
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            callback = (label, index, labels) => {
               return moment.unix(label).format('HH:mm');
            }
         }
      }]
   }
}
```

Comment: I made an example where you can see it in use: https://jsbin.com/jakavipuma/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: First of all, thank you!! If I want to work with `hh:mm` and not days I'm doing this `currentData.x = moment(oldData[i].x, "hh:mm").format('HH:mm')` and `return moment(tooltipItem[0].label).format('hh:mm')`, is this correct?

Comment: Is not working but maybe is because I have to change this too, `unit: 'week'`. What is the correct form of time unit?

Comment: Regarding the second comment: "If I want to work with hh:mm and not days...", I am not sure I get it right, if your x is timestamp you should parse it as timestamp moment.unix(data[i].x). Is that a question? Can you please add some details what exactly doesn't work: display of value on tooltip or labels?

Comment: The example of @HeadhunterKev was with dates not time, that was I ask this. I have times in bbdd not the timestamp :/

Comment: You can reformat your times to integers s.t the order between them is preserved for example define x=hours*60+minutes (for {
            x: '09:10',
            y: 89
        } you will create point with {x=9*60+10=550,y:89}); and then in tooltip and labels functions you can reverse it and get  hours = int(x/60) minutes=x%60

Comment: like this: https://jsbin.com/juzowor/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I don't understand, but I copy and paste your code and is not working, is not plotting anything...

Comment: But you see that it's working in the jsbin? I mean that you should probably remap your strings of times to integers and then in order to display labels and tooltips remap it back to the times